# Why do I get 'undefined' when passing string objects to a function in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I'm pretty new to JS and RN in general so this might be a super dumb question. I have some string objects representing a user's login details that are passed from a component on click to another function in a separate file.

loginButton.js

```
// Function called on submit button pressed
async function submitInfo( name, id, grade, email, password, { navigation }) {
    await accountChecks(name, email, password).then(() => {       
        // Do stuff
    }).catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(error);   
    });
}

// Submit button component
function InfoSubmit( { name, id, grade, email, password, navigation} ) {
    return (
        <Pressable style={styles.submitButton} onPress={() => submitInfo(name, id, grade, email, password, {navigation})}>
            <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>
                submit
            </Text>
        </Pressable>
    );
}
```

The function submitInfo calls accountChecks which looks like this:

```
function accountChecks(name, email, password) {
    // Log data and datatypes
    console.log(name, email, password);
    console.log(typeof(name), typeof(email), typeof(password));

    // Do account check stuff
}

export default accountChecks();
```

The issue is that these console.log() statements in accountChecks.js output this:

`LOG  undefined undefined undefined`

`LOG  undefined undefined undefined`

Again, sorry if this is a stupid question I'm still pretty new.

I honestly don't really know what to try, I've researched stackoverflow as well as other help forums and nobody seems to have the same problem as mee which leads me to believe that It's either a stupid problem or one unique to me.

Comment: Adding `()` after a function calls it, so `export default accountChecks();` is calling your function and then exporting the return value of that function. Instead, do `export default accountChecks;` to export the function.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're using `.then()` then you don't need `async`/`await`. Only one or the other is typically needed, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons) for the simple and quick answer:

> Adding () after a function calls it, so export default accountChecks(); is calling your function and then exporting the return value of that function. Instead, do export default accountChecks; to export the function.